# How can I get libusb hotplug events to a docker container?

Tags: docker, libusb, udev, netlink, libudev

**TD;DR**

I would like to know if there is a way to get **AP_NETLINK/NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT** messages in a docker container without using `--net host`. So I can make libusb hotplug feature to work...

**Partially answer, read Edit 1 and Edit 2**

---

I am trying to dockerize an app **(DSView)** which uses **libusb** to detect when a device is connected. It uses the **libusb hotplug** capabilities to do so.

After analyse **libusb** code I can see that, on Linux, the hotplug capabilities are based on **libudev monitors**, which relies on **AP_NETLINK/NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT** messages coming from the kernel to detect new USB devices connections.

I have read other post suggesting to run docker with this:

```
--net host -v /run/udev/control:/run/udev/control
```

This works perfectly, the problem is this creates a lot of security concerns.

After a deeper inspection of **libudev monitors** implementation, I can say that `-v /run/udev/control:/run/udev/control` is not needed since **libudev monitors** doesn't use that socket at all. **libudev** only check if that file is accessible, which means I can just do `-v $HOME/dummy:/run/udev/control` or even create an empty /run/udev/control file in the container to bypass this check.

On the other hand `--net host` is required to keep the container in the same **namespace** than the host **(main namespace)**. This is required because <s>**AP_NETLINK/NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT** messages are only send to the **main namespace**</s> (← WRONG!!!) probably is a udev requirement.

Again this is far from being ideal because by adding `--net host` we are presenting all host network resources to the container.

<s>I was considering to patch **libusb** to add **NETLINK_LISTEN_ALL_NSID** option to the socket used by the **libudev monitor** (udev_monitor.monitor.sock) but I would like to know if there is any easier way to get **AP_NETLINK/NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT** messages in all **namespaces**</s> (← Not needed, see Edit 1).

PS: `-v /run/udev/control:/run/udev/control` would be required in case we want to control host **udev** from the container (reset,add rules?, etc) which looks not that much safe at all.

PS2: In case you are curious this is the project [github](https://github.com/LordRafa/DSViewOnDocker)

---

**EDIT 1**: I have written a proof of concept reading the netlink socket directly and my surprise was that I can see **AP_NETLINK/NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT** messages in the container without adding **NETLINK_LISTEN_ALL_NSID** and without `--net host`.

**EDIT 2**: Ok I manage to find a work around to my problem. I have compiled **libusb** without udev support (`../configure --disable-udev`) and now DSView works.

It looks like udev doesn't play nice with docker. Reading libudev code I can see that there is plenty of staff preventing you to run it on a container but I really cannot see which part prevent libudev to show up the hotplug event on the monitor and/or why it does that when using the host network....

I say that this is partially answer because I would like to know why.

Comment: Please submit this as an answer and accept it! `./configure --disable-udev` does the trick for me too, and I've had a poke at this a few times over the years.